# Symfony2 security: Restrict resource for all methods but POST

Tags: php, security, symfony

I'm building a REST API, the problem I have is with a resource (applications) that can be created by anyone, but once it's created, it can only be retrieved and updated by an authenticated user with a given ROLE.

The problem is that I've protected this resource in the firewall section of my security.yml, but it doesn't let me configure it for the specific http methods.

This is my security.yml

```
security:
    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#encoding-the-user-s-password
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        OAuth2\ServerBundle\Entity\User:
                    algorithm:          sha512
                    encode_as_base64:   true
                    iterations:         5000

    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#hierarchical-roles
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                    admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }
        oauth2:
            id: oauth2.user_provider

    # the main part of the security, where you can set up firewalls
    # for specific sections of your app
    firewalls:

        api:
            pattern: ^/api/(agents|regions|applications)
            stateless: true
            simple_preauth:
                authenticator: dnd_token_authenticator

        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

    # with these settings you can restrict or allow access for different parts
    # of your application based on roles, ip, host or methods
    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/access_control.html
    access_control:
        #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
        #- { path: ^/api/applications, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, methods: POST }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have two sections in your yaml with the same pattern but different methods. One for *read_api* and one for *write_api*. You can control the security of each section one as you wish.